# Generate SSL Key in Zend Server CE - Windows

Tags: apache2, openssl, zend-server, zend-server-ce

I'm trying to generate certficate request for zend server ce on Windows (I'm using openSSL). I'm also using this online tools to generate command: tools.ssl.com

But when I tried to run, the openSSL have problem:

```
Unable to load config info from ........apache2bin/........apache2bin/openssl.cnf
error in req
```

What's possibly wrong? Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens on zend server (Windows) because openssl fails to look for configuration file. To solve this I added a new parameter:

```
-config <path to mod_ssl config file>
```